# What formula can I use to colouring in columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, spreadsheet

I am creating a planning spreadsheet for the operators to use on the shop floor.

Products have a specific time in which they are made. All I want to do is, when I type a product name into **ANY** cell, it `colours` that very column by a specific length.

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve: you type in a cell and the corresponding column shall be colored? The whole column?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We'd like to help with a specific answer, but don't have all the details we need to do so. Please **[edit]** your question to include more details of how the sheet is laid out, what you are trying to do and what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is not very specific I will provide a general answer.

The solution provided here does not make use of [macros] as you've tagged your question, but there is a way to accomplish what you are asking for using an Excel feature called "Conditional formatting".

I will provide you with a quote from an article, that I did not write myself, which explains both the concept of Conditional formatting and how to set it up in a simple scenario. Link to the article is provided below for reference (the site also contains screenshots, which I have omitted from this answer).

**Understanding conditional formatting**

Conditional formatting allows you to automatically apply formatting—such as colors, icons, and data bars—to one or more cells based on the cell value. To do this, you'll need to create a conditional formatting rule. For example, a conditional formatting rule might be: "If the value is less than $2000, color the cell red." By applying this rule, you'd be able to quickly see which cells contain values under $2000.

**To create a conditional formatting rule:**

As an example, consider a worksheet containing sales data, and we'd like to see which salespeople are meeting their monthly sales goals. The sales goal is $4000 per month, so we'll create a conditional formatting rule for any cells containing a value higher than 4000.

Select the desired cells for the conditional formatting rule.

From the Home tab, click the Conditional Formatting command. A drop-down menu will appear.
Hover the mouse over the desired conditional formatting type, then select the desired rule from the menu that appears. In our example, we want to highlight cells that are greater than $4000.

A dialog box will appear. Enter the desired value(s) into the blank field. In our example, we'll enter 4000 as our value.

Select a formatting style from the drop-down menu. In our example, we'll choose Green Fill with Dark Green Text, then click OK.

The conditional formatting will be applied to the selected cells. In our example, it's easy to see which salespeople reached the $4000 sales goal for each month.

You can apply multiple conditional formatting rules to a cell range or worksheet, allowing you to visualize different trends and patterns in your data.

source: http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/26

If you have further questions, feel free to ask them in a comment.

Comment: Hi, I know I have not made it clear. It is confusing. I want, Anywhere on the spreadsheet I type 'PRODUCT NAME' I want that column to highlighted by a certain amount. Would this still come under conditional formatting? \

Comment: If that amount is fixed, based on another set of data (lets say you have a table of 'PRODUCT NAME' vs 'PRICE', then no. In that case you want to reference another place in your excel sheet, that contains the relations between 'PRODUCT NAME' and 'PRICE'.
If this is what you want to do you need something like =VLOOKUP("PRODUCT NAME", A1:D7, 4, FALSE)
, where PRODUCT NAME is your product name, 
A1:D7 is where you want excel to search and
4 is where you want your amount is stored.

Read more [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/look-up-values-in-a-list-of-data-HP010070462.aspx)

Comment: This should really have been in another answer, since your question is now quite different, so excuse the poor formatting.